# urllib.request adding character at the beginning

Tags: python

My script as follow:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request


user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
subscribe_url = 'URL'
return_content = Request(url=subscribe_url, headers=headers)
test = urlopen(return_content).read()
print(test)
```

The actual file it's a text file like this:

```
dm1lc3M6Ly[...]PQ0K
```

But the result always adds at the beginning something that is not there

```
b'dm1lc3M6Ly[....]PQ0K'
```

The character `b'` and the final `'` should not be there. What is the issue?
Also how can I save the result in a `file.txt`?

Comment: the `b'` prefix and `'` suffix are just added by `str()` or `repr()` or the implicit `str()` used in the `print` function.  The actual data is between the first `'`  and the second `'`

Answer (score 3):

The b is not what was received from the server, but encoding modifier saying the data are bytes, instead of string:

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals